# Values on the X-axis shifting toward to zero

Tags: python, matplotlib

I generated a graph in which the values on the X-axis start from 0 and go to 1000, fifty by fifty, like 0, 50, 100, 150, ..., 900, 950, 1000. However, I want to divide the values on the X-axis by 10 (I want to convert the values on the x-axis into 0, 5, 10, 15, ..., 90, 95, 100).

Index_time is 1001

```
index_time = len(df.index)
ax.plot(np.arange(index_time), df["SoluteHBonds"], color="blue")
ranges=(np.arange(0,index_time,50))
ax.set_xticks(ranges)
```

When I divide the values on the X-axis via `np.true_divide(ranges, 10)`, all the values on the X-axis shift toward 0

On the other hand, I tried to create a list first and then divide each element by 10 but the result is still the same.

```
lst_range=list(range(0,int((index_time-1)/10),5))
ax.set_xticks([time/10 for time in lst_range])
```

What could be the problem or what is the thing that I am missing in this case?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: `ax.set_xticks(np.arange(0, len(df.index), 10))` ?  You should probably look up the definition of `np.arange`.

Comment: First of all, thanks for your reply. The code you shared is doing a similar thing that I have done. The point is the values on X-axis are going to 1000, fifty by fifty, like 0, 50, 100, 150, ..., 900, 950, 1000. However, I want to convert this into 0, 5, 10, 15, ..., 90, 95, 100. When I applied different ways, all values on the x-axis accumulate next to 0. This is the problem I have been facing.

Comment: Easiest is to just make your index go up by 0.1 instead of 1.  `ax.plot(np.arange(0, len(df.index)/10, 0.1), df["SoluteHBonds"], color="blue")` ?

Comment: Ah, you touched on a nice point indeed. Thank you very much!